# Getting Exception while Getting Unread SMS Text Messages Using WinRT API

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, sms, windows-8.1, gsm

I have **Windows 8.1** professional installed on my **ToughPad** (Panasonic FZ-G1) with **GSM** Enabled, While I am trying to get Unread Messages using **WinRT API** then my code always receives an exception, I got this code from [Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sms-SendReceive-fa02e55e)

```
//Complete code example to get unread sms text messages
 Windows.Devices.Sms.SmsDevice device = await SmsDevice.GetDefaultAsync();
 System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<ISmsMessage> results;
 results = await device.MessageStore.GetMessagesAsync(SmsMessageFilter.Unread);
```

Exception Type: ***System.ArgumentException***

Exception Message: "***Value does not fall within the expected range***."

```
and Stack Trace:  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

but I am passing an enumeration as a parameter

This Works Prefectly if I get *All Messages* or *Read Messages*